# Microsoft Bing Translate API on Android

Tags: android, api, translation, bing

i'm writing a translation app for android. Therefore I got a Bing account with a Client ID.
I tried the translation API on java and it worked.

```
import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;
import com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate;

public class trans1 {   

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Translate.setClientId("hidden");
    Translate.setClientSecret("hidden");
    String translatedText = Translate.execute("spiel", Language.GERMAN, Language.FRENCH);
    System.out.println(translatedText);
  }

}
```

Now I tried do use this in Android like this:

```
package de.androidnewcomer;

import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;
import com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class SagHalloActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Translate.setClientId("hidden");
    Translate.setClientSecret("hidden");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    try {
        String translatedText = Translate.execute("welt", Language.GERMAN, Language.FRENCH);
        Log.i("LOG", translatedText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

But I get this Errors:

```
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488):    at de.androidnewcomer.SagHalloActivity.onCreate(SagHalloActivity.java:14)
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
09-18 12:53:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(29488):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: did you use any jar files,if you used put that jar files in Libs folder and import from there

Answer (score 3):

You might need to include **Jar file** which contains `com.memetix.mst.language` package, under your **library/lib** folder which should resolve this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had the jar files but they were not in the "Android Dependencies" Folder. Now it works!

Comment: after adding microsoft-translator-java-api-0.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar to project it is not working..Any Idea??

Answer (score 0):

you have to move your code to a thread

```
new Thread() {
public void run() {
    try {
            String translatedText = Translate.execute("welt", Language.GERMAN, Language.FRENCH);
            Log.i("LOG", translatedText);`enter code here`
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}.start();
```